# What is the meaning of "daisy pom"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What is the meaning of "daisy pom"? Does the word "daisy pom" mean using some daisy flowers to make a pom shape?

Comment: Where did you see this phrase?  I've never heard of it before.

Comment: If you heard it rather than read it, then it seems possible that you misheard an Aussie with a strong accent saying "Dozy pom". "Pom" is a (lightly derogative?) term for an Englishman. "Dozy" in this sense would probably imply that the person in question hadn't been paying attention, or was slow to react to something.

Answer (score 28):

"Porn" on the internet has come to be applied to many things unrelated to sex (for example, *espresso porn*). It involves still photos and video of the thing or activity, often in close-up detail, "leaving nothing to the imagination", so to speak.

So I would imagine that "daisy porn" refers to close-up photography of the daisy flower.

P.S. Or a POM made of daisies. :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the question says 'pom' rather than 'porn', although I wouldn't rule out the original poster misreading it.

Comment: I need some new glasses, or a different font. :)

Comment: The font is terrible here - but perhaps it was as terrible where the OP read the sentence and they misread poRN for poM... I hope they'll edit to give us context :-). I've looked up [pom](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pom#Pom) and it makes no sense (a dog or a British person made of daisies?). Ant the stuff cheerleaders use is a pom-pom... So the way you originally read it makes more sense.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo the typographic term pointing at the pitfall you fell in is called `kerning`. Funnily enough, its significance can be well illustrated by the accompanying joke / meme term: `keming`.

Comment: Obvious [XKCD reference](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/kerning.png).

Answer (score 28):

A pom (sometimes known as a [pompom](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/pompom) or pompon) is a fluffy ball used for decoration. They can be made out of different materials, including yarn or paper, like [these poms for sale on Etsy](https://www.etsy.com/market/pom_wholesale).

Cheerleaders use "pom-poms"

[image: Shutterstock image of cheerleaders]

Apparently “poms” made of flowers are a popular wedding decoration. The single “pom” may be used so that the flower arrangement isn’t  confused with [“pompon” flowers](https://www.queensvarieties.com/pompons-daisy/) or cheerleader style “pompoms” which typically only come in pairs. This is a daisy pom:

[image: https://www.pinterest.com/pin/117515871497701536/]